# Mutex or another mechanism of concurrency in SQLITE3? (C language)

Tags: c, sqlite, mutex

I'm doing a functions libraries in C language that provides the basic functions to read, write and clean the registers of a sqlite3 database tables.

All the functions working properly when I execute it with a one terminal. But, my problem is when I try to use the functions from more than one terminal. For example, in a one terminal I have a program that uses a function that stores information in a table of the database file. By the other side, in an another terminal I have a program that uses a different function that stores information in another table of the same database. Then, in this environment the information doesn't store correctly. So, I think that I have to implement all the functions with a mechanisms of semaphores or mutex.

Searching in the sqlite3 documentation, I have found that there are functions that provide a mutex mechanism. These functions are the following:

1. sqlite3_mutex *sqlite3_db_mutex(sqlite3*); => Returns a pointer mutex of the database connection
2. void sqlite3_mutex_enter(sqlite3_mutex*); => Enter in critical zone
3. void sqlite3_mutex_leave(sqlite3_mutex*); => Leave critical zone

I've tried it with my functions but the results are the same, when I try to store information (writing in same database) with different processes, the information doesn't store properly. The code that I implement for the two functions that store information are more simple and are the following:

The first function => store data in table1.

```
  int add_register_table1(unsigned short int type,unsigned short int err, const char *msg, const char *agent)
{
    //Local variables:
    int rc, t0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *errMsg = 0;
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_mutex* mutex;

    //Initializing variables:
    t0 = (int) time(NULL);  //Save the current time in seconds

    //Opening the syslog.db database connection:
    rc = sqlite3_open(database.db, &db);

    if(rc != SQLITE_OK)     //Error checking
        return ERROR;

    mutex = sqlite3_db_mutex(db);   //Acquire the mutex

    //Writing data:
    sqlite3_mutex_enter(mutex);   //Enter critical zone
    sprintf (buffer,"INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('%d','%d','%d','%s','%s');", t0, type, err, 
                                                                                         msg, agent);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, buffer, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);

    sqlite3_mutex_leave(mutex);   //Leave critical zone

    if(rc != SQLITE_OK)     //Error checking
        return ERROR;

    //Closing the database connection:
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return NOERROR;
}
```

The second function, that is the same but it stores information in another table in the same database file:

```
int add_register_table2(unsigned short int type,unsigned short int err, const char *msg, const char *agent)
{
    //Local variables:
    int rc, t0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *errMsg = 0;
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_mutex* mutex;

    //Initializing variables:
    t0 = (int) time(NULL);  //Save the current time in seconds

    //Opening the syslog.db database connection:
    rc = sqlite3_open(database.db, &db);

    if(rc != SQLITE_OK)     //Error checking
        return ERROR;

    mutex = sqlite3_db_mutex(db);   //Acquire the mutex

    //Writing data:
    sqlite3_mutex_enter(mutex);   //Enter critical zone
    sprintf (buffer,"INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('%d','%d','%d','%s','%s');", t0, type, err, 
                                                                                         msg, agent);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, buffer, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);

    sqlite3_mutex_leave(mutex);   //Leave critical zone

    if(rc != SQLITE_OK)     //Error checking
        return ERROR;

    //Closing the database connection:
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return NOERROR;
}
```

My questions are the following:

· Looking at my C code, the sqlite3 mutex functions used are well used and that have to run properly, or the implementation of these in my code is wrong?

· Is there are any another kind of mechanism to implement the writing/reading database with concurrency with more than one of processes? Which are these mechanisms and how implement it?

I have stayed with this problems since few days ago, and I don't find the solve.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need mutexes (they only work inside one process anyway). What do you mean with "doesn't store correctly"?

Comment: When I say that "doesn't store correctly" I mean that when with different programs store information in also different tables but at the same time and same database file, some of this information is not stored (is lost), this is means that I can't store at the same time with different processes with sqlite3?

Comment: What file system are you using?

Comment: I'm using NTFS file system.

Comment: I have been searching more documentation about this problem and I have found that SQLITE3 works with properly concurrency at reading mode, but not at writing mode. This is true? It's impossible to write concurrently?

Comment: There is no write concurrency, but the file is locked for writing, so no data should be lost.

Comment: Then, I not have to implement any mechanism to avoid this? Sqlite does this lock automatically? So, I don't understand, why when I store the information with two processes, some of this is lost. Where is the problem, in my C code with queries as "SELECT..", in the configuration of sqlite (need one?)? Thanks a lot for your answers, I really don't know to do for fix it.

Comment: This question is about mutexes; you have not properly described your original problem.